# Session Set(Variable) Count Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, count

I have this session stored, what I need to do is to count the Quantity of the same Category.
I tried ForEach count but it only counts the session stored which is 2 ? is there any possible way that I can count the Quantity of the same Category in Session-AddedItems ?

```
"added-items": [
{
   "item_id": 1,
   "item_name": "ITEM-aut",
   "item_price": "8699",
   "item_category": "A",
   "item_quantity": 3
},

{
   "item_id": 2,
   "item_name": "ITEM-recusandae",
   "item_price": "1905",
   "item_category": "A",
   "item_quantity": 2
}
]
```

Current result Total:2

Expected Result Total:5

Comment: Do you mean to sum up the quantities of the same categories? Would be more helpful if you show the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourArray = Session::get('added-items');
$finalSum=0;
foreach($yourArray as $key=>$val)
{
    $finalSum = (int) $val['item_quantity'] + $finalSum;
}
```

untested but transmits the general idea.